# A way to keep and update only one row with TYPE=3

Tags: mysql, sql

The table:

```
ID    TYPE    USER_ID
======================
1     1       15
2     1       15
.     3       15
.     1       15
.
```

should keep multiple USER_ID's with TYPE=1 but **`only`** 0 or 1 row where TYPE=3.
In the case that TYPE=3, upon insert I need to either update or create (much like `insert on duplicate key update`) that row.
Is there a good way to accomplish this without first `SELECT`ing, and updating or inserting depending on the SELECT results in the program?
Preferably doing this in a single command, and without triggers?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to automate it. Even a trigger won't work, because triggers aren't allowed to modify the same table.

Comment: You'll have to `SELECT` anyway to know if there are multiple TYPE 3 in the table, even if it was a 'single' command. What do you use now?

Comment: select, read, decide, update or ceate...

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to add new tuple, hold the user id you added  in a variable, then

```
 delete where type = 3 and id != {Added id}
```

it would work, but I want to make the disclaimer that it seems dodgy somehow

Answer (score 0):

You can do the update with subqueries. In this case since you would want to read and write to the same tuple you would need to rename the subquery on the same table to erase the lock on that tuple.

Say you want to update the user_id of the first row of data with type=3 to 
20 do:

```
UPDATE tbl SET user_id=20 WHERE id=
(SELECT A.id FROM (SELECT MIN(id) id
FROM tbl 
WHERE type=3) A);
```

See [**DEMO ON SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab429/1).